# Google Tag Manager tags fire but do not show on page

Tags: google-tag-manager

Tag Manager is set up correctly and is effectively sending download events to Analytics. But a custom HTML tag is not displaying. The Tag Manager Preview function shows that the tag is firing correctly at the `Container loaded` stage but the script is not shown on the page source. There are no errors in the console.

```
<!-- Start of Survicate (www.survicate.com) code -->
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        (function(w) {
          var s = document.createElement('script');
          s.src = 'https://survey.survicate.com/workspaces/a527ta37d10/web_surveys.js';
          s.async = true;
          var e = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          e.parentNode.insertBefore(s, e);
        })(window);
      </script>
    <!-- End of Survicate code -->
```

What's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: When I look in the network tab I see the file is loaded, so there does not seem to be an actual issue.

Comment: Except that the tags which I have set up and which Preview says are fired do not actually show. That's quite key. I agree it's hard to debug though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem, your script shows up:

[image: script inserted into page]

My educated guess would be that you use the source view, which does not render dynamically inserted code. Use the "elements" tab in the browsers dev tools instead.